# Panda's Update information based on bins / cutting

Tags: pandas

I'm working on a dataset which has a large amount of missing information.
I understand I could use FillNA but i'd like to base my updates on the binned values of another column.

Selection of missing data:

```
missing = train[train['field'].isnull()]
```

Bin the data (this works correctly):

```
filter_values = [0, 42, 63, 96, 118, 160]
labels = [1,2,3,4,5]
out = pd.cut(missing['field2'], bins = filter_values, labels=labels)
counts = pd.value_counts(out)
print(counts)
```

Now, based on the bin assignments,  I would like to set the correct bin label, to the `missing/train['field']` for all data assigned to this bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

You just need to `fillna`

```
train['field'] = train['field'].fillna(out)
```

Comment: @jcuypers glad I could help!

Comment: looked at your profile. impressive. really :-)  any tips for amateur data and ML enthousiats (resources) ?

Comment: @jcuypers dive in head first and embrace the struggle.  The coursera ML courses are fun and pretty good.

Comment: Great. thanks. just finished week 3 of Andrew NG's course

Comment: @jcuypers I enjoyed that one a lot.  I wrote everything in python and numpy after I wrote in octave.

Comment: Yeah, he's really good and the content is accessible enough. you should create your own. Anyway the ML detected our discussion as not related to the question:-)  Thanks again. If you want to do a kaggle let me know :-)

Comment: @jcuypers will do!